# Add new codeowner to CODEOWNERS not working

Tags: github, github-codeowners

I was removed from a CODEOWNERS file and then readded and now Github is not tagging the other codeowners to my pull requests, is this a bug and how can I fix it?

Here is an example of what the file looks like:

```
#These owners will be the default owners for everything in the repo. Unless a later match takes precedence, the following folks will be requested for review when someone opens a pull request.

- @s @f @m @d
```

Comment: You have to show the file. Did you use multiple lines for the same files/directories?

Comment: You need `*` for "everything", not `-`.

Comment: Yeah prettier force changes it to that, I will try to change it back